# How to specify gitlab url after installing apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, gitlab

I installed first the gitlab-ce on my local desktop ubuntu (used as a server) and it was okay and able to connect to it through IP address  `http://192.168.1.6/` from other computers on the same network of course

Now and after installing the apache server I'm not able to access to gitlab-ce and instead of the gitlab page I see the apache page !

what I want to do is to make gitlab accessible through `http://192.168.1.6/gitlab` , is it possible ?

here the actual configuration I have :

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
external_url 'http://gitlab.mostafa-home.com:9999'
# Disable nginx
nginx['enable'] = false
# Give apache user privileges to listen to GitLab
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http, and add a proxypass directive to your configuration:

```
ProxyPass "/gitlab" "http://localhost:9999/"
```

Comment: should I make  these in : /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf ?

Comment: default will do, unless you intend to have a more complex configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hello mostafa i need to have 50rep+ to answer your comment. So i put my commenbt in answer here.

### First create your configuration file :

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab
```

### Create a symlink to sites-enabled :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab
```

### Add what you have to add in the conf file.

### Restart apache server :

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

### Check status of apache server :

```
systemctl status apache2
```